# FFMPEG HLS stream not buffering in video.js

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, video.js, http-live-streaming

I'm using the command below to generate an HLS stream that I'm then playing via video.js This is running on an EC2 instance and I think the output network bandwidth might be pretty low as I can't get the video to play without chugging and stopping every once in a while.

Do you know if there are any other ffmpeg settings I should use to make the streaming better?

Is there any setting in Video.JS that could allow me to setup a buffer time within the player?

Any idea why the buffer setting in FFMPEG is not taken into account in Video.JS?

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -s 1280x720 -framerate 60 -r 30  -i :0.0+nomouse -f alsa -ac 2 -i pulse -vcodec libx264 -acodec libfdk_aac -crf 23 -pix_fmt yuv420p -s 640x360 -bufsize 2000k -g 30 -f hls -hls_time 1 -hls_list_size 0 -hls_allow_cache 1 -tune zerolatency index.m3u8
```